# DRM KMS and Frame buffer

Tags: drivers, graphics, kms, drm

I need to build a graphics driver for E4690 card with ATI Raden RV730 GPU on it. Its only beginning. I am trying to understand the relationship between the following from linux sources:

1. DRM
2. KMS
3. Frame buffer

What is the purpose for each? How do they relate? Can DRM work without KMS or KMS without DRM. I am kind of going in an infinite loop understanding this. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You are planning on creating a graphics driver from scratch?

Comment: Yes @phk. for a completely new OS. The devices in this OS are not file based as in linux. So needed to understand the architecture properly.